# R conditional replacement data frame values

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe

I want to update a dataframe column (df$d) with the result of a mathematical operation on one or more other columns (df$b, df$c), conditional on the value of another column (df$a).

```
set.seed(55)
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), c = rnorm(10), d = 0)
df$d[df$a > 0] <- df$b[df$a > 0] / df$c[df$a > 0]
```

The third line produces the expected values for df$d. Is there a way to write this more succinctly? I'm especially interested in options that do not require me to repeat the logical index.

For example, this style of expression works in Python/Pandas and requires only one instance of '[df$a > 0]' on the left-hand side of the assignment operator:

```
df$d[df$a > 0] <- df$b / df$c
```

Thank you for any and all advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `data.table` instead and your life will be much better:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df) # or construct it same way: dt = data.table(a = rnorm(10),...)

dt[a > 0, d := b/c]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
transform(df, d = ifelse(a > 0, b/c, d))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
transform(df, d = b / c * (a > 0))
```

will do the trick. This solution does *not* depend on the existence of the column `d`. Hence, you don't need to initialize the column with zeroes.